# How is a literal list having one element represented unambiguously in perl?

Tags: perl

I need a function to return a list, which is consumed as sole input list to `map BLOCK LIST`. I wrote `return (6);` because I wanted to return **a list having one element**, but this *looks same as* **a scalar enclosed in parentheses**. Will it be interpreted the way I want? Need I use ugly things like: `return @{[6]};` to enforce my intention?

Comment: Function always returns a list. The only question is how many elements are in such list.

Comment: Perhaps you should give us your test cases that makes you think Perl acts the way you think it does, so that we can explain where your analysis falters.

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering whether the return value will be a suitable input for map.

Comment: You really don't need the parentheses, and your nasty anonymous array dereference is only adding noise -- the result is identical. Use `return 6`, or just `6`. Do you have a case where you are getting problems when presenting that to `map`?

Comment: @Сухой27 "Function always returns a list" is not correct. There is such a thing as scalar context (as I cover in my answer).

Comment: @KevinReid context may affect behavior of what is returned, but in all circumstances there is only list of scalars coming out as the result of the function.

Comment: @Сухой27 Well, I suppose you can model it that way if you want, but I think it's an unhelpful model, because it doesn't *inherently* have the rule you'd have to state explicitly: "it is never possible to return more or less than exactly one value in scalar context"

Comment: thanks @Borodin i tried `perl -e 'print map { $_*$_ } 5'` which worked as I intended. I had never encountered literal scalar passed to `map` before, so i was unsure.

Comment: "List of scalars" just means "zero or more scalars". There's no actual "list" variable type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**There is no ambiguity here, and you *cannot* return a list unconditionally.**

In Perl 5, every expression, including a subroutine call, has a *context*, which is either *list context* (returning zero or more values) or *scalar context* (returning exactly one value). A `return` statement propagates the context of the subroutine call to the expression in the `return` statement. Let's suppose you're trying to return a list with several elements:

```
return (6, 7, 8);
```

This is *not* guaranteed to be a list. If the sub is called in scalar context, then the *comma expression* in the `return` statement is in scalar context also, and the behavior of the comma expression in scalar context is to return the rightmost value, here `8`.

If you instead used a temporary array,

```
return @{[6, 7, 8]}
```

then if it is called in scalar context you will get the behavior of arrays in scalar context, which is to return *the number of elements in the array*.

All of the above applies to one-element lists just as much as the three-element lists in the example.

Some general facts:

- There is no way to forcibly return a list — you can only return what the caller asks for.
- There is no systematic choice for what happens if you invoke a list-y thing in scalar context — the number of elements in the list which would be returned in list context is a common choice, but not universal.
- If you want to have a well-specified subroutine, you cannot say “it always returns a list”; you must specify what happens when it is required to return a scalar. (You could decide that it will always `die`, if you wanted.)
- If you want to make an explicit choice based on whether the call is in scalar or list context, you can use the poorly-named builtin `wantarray`, which returns true if the subroutine was called in list context.

This is the closest thing to what you asked for that can actually exist. Note that there are no parentheses — parentheses don't affect context.

```
die "can't be scalar" unless wantarray;
return 6;
```

Comment: Forcing list regardless of context (in scalar it gets right most element/not the size) => https://eval.in/238061

Comment: @Сухой27 That is not an example of forcing list context; that is making an array and then taking a slice of it in scalar context. "Slices in scalar context return the last item of the slice." — `perldata` docs

Comment: I didn't wrote *forcing list context* but forcing list like behavior. :)

Comment: "A function always returns a list" by @Сухой27 cleared my present doubt. I understood that a function returns a list but the calling context decides what it becomes. Thank you Kevin for describing what actually happens inside. I now understand that there is no ambiguity because evaluation of expressions is contextual by design. I just needed to provide the context I want, which I did.